# How to create an overlay and load it in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hey guys I have began some introductory level Firefox Add-ons programming. I am trying create an add-on that has an overlay on the screen that has 5 text boxes. The purpose of the text boxes is it will alter 5 different Textbox nodes on a specific webpage (the webpage is an internal page at my job). I am looking to create an overlay that is similar to this

[image]

Instead of it saying Firefox Hello it would have 5 textboxes instead. I am unsure how to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is usually called a [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel).

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you for the link!